# Mixture of two components

Tags: probability, distributions, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Consider a univariate probability density function $p(x)$ that is a mixture of $2$ probability density functions with weights $\eta, 1-\eta$ and $\eta\in (0,1)$: 
$$
p(x)=(1-\eta)g(x)+\eta f(x) \hspace{1cm} \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$

Suppose we know $p(x)$ and $g(x)$ at every $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Our professor made the following point: without further restrictions we cannot back out $\eta, f(x)$. To see that, it is sufficient to observe that
$$
(1-\eta)g(x)+\eta f(x)=(1-\eta/2)g(x)+\eta/2 (-g(x)+2f(x))
$$
Hence, $p(x)$ can be generated by $\{\eta, f(x)\}$ and by $\{\eta/2, -g(x)+2f(x)\}$.

**Question**: I see the point. However, I don't understand how we are sure that $(g(x)+2f(x))$ is a probability density function. Specifically, it is not necessarily positive. Can't that requirement allow to get rid of the second solution?

Comment: I think you have a mistake in the second formula. It should be $\left(1 - \frac{\eta}{2}\right) g\left(x\right) + \frac{\eta}{2} \left(2f\left(x\right) - g\left(x\right)\right)$. Then, it integrates to 1. But there is another problem - you are not promised that density is positive, thus it is not a distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the typo. Am I right to say then that the point of my professor does not actually show what he wanted to say?

Comment: First, their point stands because they showed that *exist* case where the pair $\left(f\left(x\right), \eta\right)$ is not uniquely recoverable. Note that in fact, this example can be strengthened to show that you can always find other decompositions.

Comment: Thanks. Is this correct: they have shown that $p(x)$ can be generated by $\{\eta, f(x)\}$ with $2f(x)\geq g(x)$  and by $\{\eta/2, -g(x)+2f(x)\}$

Comment: Yes, though I would phrase it as "they have shown that, in the case where $2f\left(x\right) \ge g\left(x\right)$, $p\left(x\right)$ can be generated by ..."

Comment: I've updated my answer. Note that in fact, you can always find a second solution, if you are given only $p$ and $g$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following presents a general way to recover another decomposition of a mixture model. In essence, we can always move some of the mass covered by $g\left(x\right)$ to the second component.

Let $\beta>\frac{\eta}{1-\eta}$ and $\alpha=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\beta}}>\eta>0$ (so that $\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{\beta}=1$). Note that 
$$p\left(x\right)=\left(1-\frac{\eta}{\alpha}\right)g\left(x\right)+\frac{\eta}{\alpha}\left(\alpha f\left(x\right)+\alpha\frac{g\left(x\right)}{\beta}\right)
$$

Note that $\frac{\eta}{\alpha} \in \left(0, 1\right)$ and that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha f\left(x\right)+\alpha\frac{g\left(x\right)}{\beta}dx=\alpha+\alpha\frac{1}{\beta}=\alpha+\alpha\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}-1\right)=1
$$

Thus the pair $\left(\frac{\eta}{\alpha}, \alpha f\left(x\right) + \frac{\alpha}{\beta}g\left(x\right)\right)$ generates $p\left(x\right)$ from $g\left(x\right)$.

We can set $\beta = 2 \frac{\eta}{1 - \eta}$, and we get

$$p\left(x\right) = \left(1-\frac{1+\eta}{2}\right)g\left(x\right)+\frac{1+\eta}{2}\left(\frac{2\eta}{1+\eta}f\left(x\right)+\frac{1-\eta}{1+\eta}g\left(x\right)\right)$$